# Hiding Bezier curve handles

Tags: interface, bezier-curves

I use control right click to make shapes with bezier curves and the handles get in the way.  Is there a way to hide the handles.

I've looked and I can not find a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for the **Curve Display** settings on the 3D viewport (accessible by pressing <kbd>N</kbd>)

There you can disable the handles, or change how the normals are displayed

[image]

Comment: Thank you, cegaton.  It could not be clearer. I will pass on the favor in some form.