# Image delineation

Tags: mesh

Is there a quick way in blender that I can use to delineate all the boundaries of the drawing and make them appear on a uv sphere, making it interactive in blender?

P.S. I'm in cycles

[image: In blender]

[image: Something like that but as a mesh]

Comment: Hello. What do you mean by "interactable" ? also is it mandatory to have the texture on a sphere ? Can you explain a bit more editing your question ?

Comment: I meant interactive :\ I've adjusted the question

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear. What boundaries do you want as a mesh? Guessing you want  the boundaries of the drawing as a mesh you can use GIMP.

Open up the image in GIMP and select all lines. This is best done using the 'Select by Colour Tool'. Having everything selected, you have to click on 'To Path' in the Select Tab. Then go to the path window (by default on the right hand side) and right click your path and select 'Export Path'. Name your file *.svg. Then activate the addon 'Import-Export: Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) 1.1 format' in your Blender user preferences. Save your user settings if you want it to be activated on startup from now on. Then go to 'File' -> 'Import' -> 'Scalable Vector Graphics (.svg)'. Choose your file and press 'Import SVG'. Now you have your path imported as a curve. In order to convert it to a mesh press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while hovering over the 3D View with your mouse. Then select 'Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text'.[image: The different steps]

Comment: Your response is almost perfect, it's just the last part what I don't want, the texture should appear on a uv sphere. My bad!

Comment: If you mean that the mesh should appear on the sphere the way the texture does I can't think of a definite way of doing so. I'd fiddle around with the warp tool (press 'Space' and type in warp in edit mode or mesh ->transform ->warp). Note that it uses the 3d cursor as reference point and not the object's origin. It also takes your POV into account. As an example you can turn a subdivided plane (2 blender units * 2 blender units) into a sphere by warping it 180° from front view and 360° from right view. The mesh has to be 1 blender unit above the 3d cursor. I hope that that's what you want.

Comment: @DavidS., for the sphere aspect http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/how-to-animate-morphing-a-rectangular-plane-into-a-sphere or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere/53172#53172