# How do I turn an imported SVG into a sphere?

Tags: modeling

I am very new to blender and am making some models for use with Three.js.

The model I have created is a logo, as show below. I am quite happy with this but was curious if I could take it further.

[image]

How can i make this a sphere, instead of a disc? The resulting sphere would still have the white regions 'indented'.

The source shapes are SVG files. One file per colour region of the model.

1. Import SVG from Inkscape
2. Add materials.
3. Extrude all regions
4. Undo last extrude on white region.

Please see the example SVG file for the dark gray region.

[image: Example dark gray region]

Again, I am a bit of a noob, so please be as verbose as possible. Links to similar tutorials are most welcome.

Comment: so you want to bend, or warp your logo mesh in to the shape of a sphere? If so read this question http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/52904/2217

Comment: @David I would like a solid sphere. However, the while paths are indented. I am imagining two spheres, one smaller than the other.

Comment: @David, more like a materials sphere.... https://wiki.blender.org/uploads/3/36/LeatherMaterialSample.png but with the paths from my model instead of the blender logo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no quick 'one-button-press' way to do what you want easily, especially not directly from the SVG imported Curve Objects. Curve objects are not very suited for modeling other than 'extrusion based shapes.

You can however quickly simulate an approximation of a 3D object by projection. It will yield very bad topology, and the resulting object will not be very suited for further modelling, but visually it may satisfy your needs.

Import your SVG curves, fix their center with the 3D cursor, and center them at the scene origin.

[image: Curve origin]

Add two sphere objects and scale one to fit the largest radius, the other to fit the smallest radius. Move the logos above your spheres

[image: Add Sphere]

[image: Sphere radius]

By this specific order select the matching curve > the select the corresponding sphere radius.
Enter *Edit Mode*, select all faces press the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> Menu > search for *Knife Project* and then tick the option *Cut Through*.

[image: Knife Project]

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to invert selection and quickly remove the unwanted faces.

[image: Invert Selection]

Repeat with the other curves for the corresponding spheres.

[image: Knife Project]

Assign materials to chunks of your mesh. Press <kbd>L</kbd> while hovering a part of the mesh to select all linked geometry

[image: Material Assignment]

In the end add a *Solidify* modifier and an *EdgeSplit* modifier to your objects.

[image: Modifiers]

Have in mind that this is an approximation, and will not necessarily look good viewed from all angles.

Answer (score 0):

The technique that shown in the first comment is suitable. In the curve section of that answer, click the *Extrude* option and insert the amount that you want. After that go to:

*Object > Convert to > Mesh from curve*

Next, change the point of origin by selecting:

*Object > Transform > Origin to center of mass*

Select the object and go into edit mode, if the mesh is selected, hit the <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude and then <kbd>S</kbd> for scale.

It's possible to do so in the original SVG format, but it's not always recommended for a uniform mesh. The SVG file may have too many points which translate into vertices, or they may not be evenly distributed throughout the object, thus giving the object a highly irregular mesh to work with.

If that's major concern however, it's probably best to create it all in Blender instead.