# "Cutting" a logo into a rounded shape?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, svg

I'm new to Blender but not 3D modeling. I'm struggling to translate what I know to this interface, but I'm getting there thanks to all the tutorials and efforts this great Blender community has created.
Thank you! It's amazingly helpful.

I need some help with how I should approach this model (if you point in the name of the tool, I can go find the resources on it, I'm really looking for the term of what I'm trying to accomplish).

I have [an SVG logo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5iY7PoTfKAMVkl2VG5DT2pLdGJrQnk5M2U3bGt5bmlGQWFV). I'd like to shape this logo to a sphere or other roundish shape and give it a look like it was "router cut" into the face of the shape.

I would like the logo to be about 2mm recessed on all sides.

[image: Logo Image]

I was thinking I could

- Extrude the logo
- Make an inner shape
- Make an outer shape
- Use the outer shape to "cut" the extruded logo to the face of the
  rounded shape. (Boolean)
- Use the inner shape to "cut" the extruded logo depth (boolean) to
  give me a sliver the side I'd like to notch out of the rounded shape.
- And then Boolean again on duplicates of the shapes to remove the
  junction of these two.

Seems like there should be an easier way to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you model 'a sphere with a shell' like object?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66942/how-would-you-model-a-sphere-with-a-shell-like-object)

Comment: Also see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59219/how-do-i-turn-an-imported-svg-into-a-sphere/59226#59226

Comment: The solution you think is too complicated sounds fine to me.  Trust me: there are much more complicated problems than yours.  Danial's Knife Project would allow you to extrude-scale which allows for a slightly different style of cut.

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to convert your logo into a curve/mesh outline, you could then use **Knife Project** to cut it out of your base object. Then you would simply need to extrude the cutout area to the desired depth.