# How to curve a plane around a cylinder?

Tags: modeling

So I have a cylinder (Or any curved shape) and I want to wrap the door to it.
I can give the door more depth and move it close to the cylinder but the edges won't be equal from all sides, and I want them to be equal.
So any idea how can I wrap it around the cylinder?

[image]

Comment: Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere/52905#52905