# How can I make the decoration to take the shape of any object

Tags: modeling, modifiers, 3d-printing

I'm trying to make a design of [decoration](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-AG7qG-8LOnw/VQRj9R-Z_bI/AAAAAAAAB9c/S0prR3Ow6GM/s1600/%D8%B2%D8%AE%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%A9%2B%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%A9.png) to be like the shape of " sphere, car, body ... etc "  for example I convert an image of decoration to be SVG then I make it like sphere shape .

[image][image][image]

as I used "simple deform" modifier to make it, but I can't use same modifier to make the decoration like the "heart, car, building, face ... etc ", for example can I replace the wires in the below heart with shown decoration in the beginning ? or make the decoration like shape of the car "if I have a car shape" ... then I can print it using 3D printer .
   [image]

I hope my idea is clear for you .

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere/53172#53172

Comment: Oh, that is useful, but I put the sphere as example, what about if I need mask the decoration on car to take the shape of the car ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrap curve around sphere](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and state what you really want... Is this for an illustration, animation, 3D assets or 3D printing? Is this a texure for an object or are you looking to recreate the geometry as well? Would you rather use an SVG curve file than a raster image?There are many ways to do what you want depending on your intended use.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this effect with the Shrinkwrap modifier as long as the pattern you are trying to apply is a mesh. For this to work best you should create a volume of your pattern, preferably spherical, then apply the shrinkwrap modifier with the "project" setting.

I would suggest keeping the pattern flat, then adding the thickness after it has shrinkwrapped around the object (possibly with the solidify modifier).

An alternative is also the Cast modifier, however this works only on geometric objects like spheres or tubes.