# 3D Earth using curve to mesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, bezier-curves, svg

I'm trying to make a globe model for earth using fairly accurate projections. I've been able to convert the SVG into mesh, then into a sphere using [this guide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere) with Simple Deforms. However, since the vertices are only on the outline, when I deform the shape, it turns out like this monstrosity.

[image]

Is there a good way to easily add some curvature so this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a remesh modifier (before extruding and even deforming to a sphere) ?

Comment: @ChameleonScales I have not. I'm only a few weeks into using blender. I'll look into it!

Comment: @ChameleonScales If I try to remesh before extruding the mesh it gets destroyed.

Comment: @ChameleonScales Nevermind, I can just extrude then remesh, remove the extra vertical subdivisions and then deform sphereically. So far so good, thanks!

Comment: @Sjael please write an answer detailing what you did to solve your problem. It would help other users that have similar questions. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I followed the instruction on [how to deform a curve to a sphere](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere), but before you apply the deforms, simply convert the curve to a mesh then use a remesh modifier. Then when you deform you get this, with a nice curve all the way around. Thanks to @ChameleonScales for the help!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem I see with using an SVG file, that the once it gets converted to a mesh the topology is going to be a mess, mostly long triangles that are not going to deform or subdivide well.

It might be easier to use an image to do the displacement on a sphere (and use it also to create the texture).

[image]

[image]