# World map as displacement map on a sphere distorted

Tags: mesh, displacement

I am trying to use an image of a world map as a displacement map for a sphere. Later I want to export the mesh for 3D printing, with the continents looking like engraved into a sphere. I am new to Blender.

This is the image I am currently using:

[image: map]

This image is basically the "Land/Ocean map" from [this Blender tutorial](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/earth-cycles), just with an erode/dilate filter applied. Because this guy is using it as a texture in Blender I am assuming it is a suitable projection.

What I tried so far:

- Create a UV sphere
- Add a Subsurf modifier with 7 subdivisions
- Add a Displace modifier with this image as texture and a strength of 0.02

The problem is now that while Europe and Africa are squeezed horizontally...

[image: europeafrica]

... Australia's east coast is extremely stretched out.

[image: australia]

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a completely different, better way?

[image]

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84854/uv-sphere-unwrap-perfect-square/84859#84859 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/what-is-the-best-way-to-unwrap-a-sphere/13928#13928 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82655/3d-earth-using-curve-to-mesh/82662#82662