# Displacement on a cylinder or creating a texture roller

Tags: displacement, svg

I am a blender beginner and was wondering how to create a so called 3D printable (the mesh needs to be highres) texture roller as this one:
 [image]
https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3029293

I first tried creating a basic cylinder combined with a sub-surface- and a displacement-modifier, what for some reason did not work for me.. Even when creating a seam and uv-unwrapping I still had no luck...

Secondly i tried to follow this tutorial [World map as displacement map on a sphere distorted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123810/world-map-as-displacement-map-on-a-sphere-distorted) but while I managed to get the bump mapping working, displacment mapping in a similiar way (using the same overall structure) did not work correctly -> Regarding this approach, i am wondering how to "bake/apply" the mods before exporting the mesh to be printed.

Lastly - and for me actually most interesting - I thought to create a 2D drawing (either manual or via .svg import) to project it on a cylinder, but did not even finde a way to do this

As non of the afformentioned approaches worked at all and me getting depressed after working on this for a while, I decided to post here.

If anyone could help me or at least pinpoint me in the right direction I would be really great full!

Cheers JI

Comment: Any other approach as to how to create this geometry would also be great!

Answer (score 2):

1.Add a cylinder, adjust its scale in edit mode and cut the faces to squares with Ctrl+R, mark a seam and unwrap it.

2. Add a subdivision surface modifier with 3-5 viewport value and apply it.
3. Browse in your texture in the "Texture" properties tab.
4. Add a displace modifier, select your texture, set the coordinates to UV, set the Midlevel 0 or 1 to preserve the original geometry and set the strenght to a low value then apply the modifier.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it has been working perfectly i feel a bit stupid now to be honest... 
I beleif i did not tick the "texture coordinates" to be "uv", eventhough i have read about it....

Any tips for a projection of curves onto a surface -> most interested in projection onto a cylinder/ a convex body?  
On the other hand I was using a "full" cylinder and totally misunderstood, that the "top" should either be nonexistent or needs an extra seam..