# Shrinkwrap a shape onto a mesh?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to figure this out, but I cant find a way to do it. 
I want to wrap this shape on to this "cup" model.

Is there anyway to do this??

[image: My reference image]

[image]

Comment: Please show/explain at what point in the process the shrinkwrap is failing.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere