# 3D Jigsaw Sphere

Tags: modeling, mesh, uv, knife-tool

I've made a sphere which is UV wrapped with a picture of a world map, and then made hollow by using the 'solidify' modifier. I was wondering if I can break up this hollow sphere into a 3D jigsaw puzzle, cutting it up into curved jigsaw pieces which can fit together to make the whole globe.

Alternatively if this is not possible, is it possible to cut into simpler pieces such as simple curved squares instead. I am completely new to Blender and I am doing this for a school project, so simple and easy to understand advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A possibility is to start with a flat (2d subdivided surface) and make it spherical. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/how-to-animate-morphing-a-rectangular-plane-into-a-sphere/24053#24053

Comment: @lemon thanks so much for that fast response, sounds like it could work!

Comment: Depending on what projection you are using for the world map and how you unwrapped the mesh another approach might be useful. You could place a puzzle texture (black and white pieces and outlines) on a copy of your sphere and then use a displacement modifier. Then from that you can do a boolean with the original sphere. to make cuts at the piece boundaries.