# wrap unwrapped sphere back into a sphere

Tags: modeling, uv, edit-mode, transforms, uv-image-editor

So I have this flat/unwrapped Vector print template for a custom soccer/football design.

[image: pdf]

[image: unwrap]

I want to wrap it back into a sphere in order to preview the design as well as use texture paint on the sphere rather than working on the flat unwrap directly.

What's the best way to do this?

Blend and Vector files: [download](https://easyupload.io/l5b052)

Comment: Upload your blend file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and [edit] the question to add the link

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere/52905#52905