# Warp multiple meshes into sphere

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode

I imported curves from svg file, converted them to meshes and filled them. [image]

Now i would like to warp them into a sphere, but whenever i try *Mesh > Transform > Warp*, it only affects one object.

[image]

However when i try <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>180</kbd> it affects all objects, just what i would like to achieve with warp.

[image]

Anyone know how to make *Mesh > Transform > Warp* affects all objects? Or alternatively a better way to bend this into a sphere since that is my end goal.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere/52905#52905

Comment: you could also try this method with Simple Deform: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/how-to-animate-morphing-a-rectangular-plane-into-a-sphere