# Wrapping SVG map around sphere so indiviudal states can be selected

Tags: modeling, modifiers, svg

In Blender 3.4.1, how do I manipulate a vector image of a 2D world map (containing thousands of individual curves) around a sphere without joining them all together?

I have succeeded at doing this (see below) but only by joining all the curves in the imported SVG (all >4,000 of them) and then using 2 [Simple Deform](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/simple_deform.html) bends on the joined shape.   However, I cannot seem to un-join (separate) them once they have been transformed onto the sphere.

IOW, how can I create something like what I created below, but with each country (or state) being an individual shape?

### Original

2D image: imported SVG.

Note how countries or states (in this case, Utah, western USA) can be selected individually

[image: original 2D SVG]

created via: [Natural Earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/) shapefile --> [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/) DXF file --> Adobe Illustrator SVG --> imported into Blender.

### Result

Perfect, other than the fact that individual nation/states cannot be selected individually.

With modifiers shown:
[image: with modifiers showing]

Sphere added in center to aid in visibility
[image: with sphere added]

[Link to SVG file](https://svgshare.com/i/qpu.svg)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrap curve around sphere](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!  I am trying it right now, will reply with my results as soon as I am finished.

Comment: Ah, so when I attempt to implement the link, I get stuck at the same place (adding the deform modifiers).  If I join the (4958 total) curves together I lose the ability to select individual nations/states on the globe once it is formed.  But if I do not join the curves, I cannot use deform modifiers on a group of curves, only individual ones.  As in, the option is not present.

Comment: I added a link to my particular SVG file at the bottom of my post.  I feel that my question concerns more how to do this with *many* curves making up a plane, rather than doing it with a *single* plane/curve.  I apologize if I did not articulate this well in my original post.