# Translating a 2d tesselation onto a 3d sphere?

Tags: modeling, mesh

So, I made a tesselation in tiled.art, of my Premier League team, the Wolves, and wanted to tile these onto a sphere - they're basically hexagons with some sides subdivided and pushed in, making a decagon, if I'm correct . However, if i want to use a truncated icosphere or similar, I also have to use pentagons, or similar, but I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this.
[image]

Comment: This might help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere